# How to display each value of JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

```js
<script>

alert('sorry this code snipprt was done by mistake ');

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>News</title>
 </head>
<body>
sorry this code snippet was done by mistake 
</body>

</html>
```

```js
<script>

alert('sorry this code snipprt was done by mistake ');

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>News</title>
 </head>
<body>
sorry this code snippet was done by mistake 
</body>

</html>
```

I am using news API by URL: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news-in&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx , i am using query in Javascript to decode `JSON`.

I am expecting this result as shown in image
[expecting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yALKx.jpg)

I have tried this codes

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 
var c = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=business&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

function myFun() {

    var yt = '';
$.ajax({
 url: c,
 dataType: 'json',
 type:'get',
 cache: false,
 success: function(data) {

  var art = data;

  var source = art.articles;

        var i;

  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
   var x = art.articles[i];

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<style type=text/css>button{border-radius:16px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black;font-size:15px;fontalign:center;cursor:pointer;position:relative;height:16%;width:flex-start;display:inline-flex;itemalign:center;} img{border-top-left-radius: 16px;border-bottom-left-radius:16px;} h3{font-size:38px;width:flex-start;height:flex-start;} </style> <div><li><a href="'+x.url+'"><button><center><img src="'+x.urlToImage+'" height="247px" width="480px"></center><h3>'+x.title+'</h3></button></a><br><br><br></li></div>';
  }
         
 }
});
 
}

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>News</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFun();">

<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but this code display only the last values of `JSON` and all value is skipped as shown in image
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxd0J.png)

Comment: with innerHtml you overwrite every loop your html.

Comment: You only have one html element with id result, so when your loop goes through the element it changes only that specific element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually overwriting every time the content of the div with id="result"
Try modifying the code as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += ...
```

Note the +=

Comment: Or cache the intermediate strings of HTML and append once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your for should look something like:

```
let articlesHtml = '';
for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
     let article = art.articles[i];
     articlesHtml += '<li><a href="' + article.url + '"><button><center><img src="' + article.urlToImage + '" height="247px" width="480px"></center><h3>' + article.title + '</h3></button></a><br><br><br></li>';
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<ul>' + articlesHtml + '</ul>';
```

Notice, that I'm using 'ul' around 'li' items.
While the style, should be added once to the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>News</title>

    <style type=text/css>button{border-radius:16px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black;font-size:15px;fontalign:center;cursor:pointer;position:relative;height:16%;width:flex-start;display:inline-flex;itemalign:center;} img{border-top-left-radius: 16px;border-bottom-left-radius:16px;} h3{font-size:38px;width:flex-start;height:flex-start;} </style> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFun();">

<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += div

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 
var c = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=business&apiKey=0f6f7e4df5a8411e867b975d70bf0a1f';

function myFun() {

    var yt = '';
$.ajax({
 url: c,
 dataType: 'json',
 type:'get',
 cache: false,
 success: function(data) {

  var art = data;

  var source = art.articles;

        var i;

  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
   var x = art.articles[i];

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<style type=text/css>button{border-radius:16px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black;font-size:15px;fontalign:center;cursor:pointer;position:relative;height:16%;width:flex-start;display:inline-flex;itemalign:center;} img{border-top-left-radius: 16px;border-bottom-left-radius:16px;} h3{font-size:38px;width:flex-start;height:flex-start;} </style> <div><li><a href="'+x.url+'"><button><center><img src="'+x.urlToImage+'" height="247px" width="480px"></center><h3>'+x.title+'</h3></button></a><br><br><br></li></div>';
  }
         
 }
});
 
}

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>News</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFun();">

<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the entire innerHTML in a variable and then use it like this:

```
var requiredHTML = '';    
for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            var x = art.articles[i];
            requiredHTML+= '<div><li><a href="'+x.url+'"><button><center><img src="'+x.urlToImage+'" height="247px" width="480px"></center><h3>'+x.title+'</h3></button></a><br><br><br></li></div>';
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<style type=text/css>button{border-radius:16px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black;font-size:15px;fontalign:center;cursor:pointer;position:relative;height:16%;width:flex-start;display:inline-flex;itemalign:center;} img{border-top-left-radius: 16px;border-bottom-left-radius:16px;} h3{font-size:38px;width:flex-start;height:flex-start;}</style>' + requiredHTML;
```